# How to define clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering, biostatistics, hierarchical-clustering

The data contains information about the genes causing breast cancer in our body. My aim is to find the most effective gene on breast cancer in our body. The code that I have first divides my sample by clustering and then shows number of genes which can separate samples into those clusters. To do the second function it uses " mRMR.classic (mRMRe.ensemble)" package from R. We want in this code is that instead of dividing samples by hierarchial clustering, we want to define clusters by ourselves and then this should find probesets to differentiate those two groups. However, I don't have any idea about how I can make this change. If you help me, I'm really gonna be happy.

Answer (score 0):

you have too much option for classification. begining with linear discriminat will be easier if you are not familiar to machine learning alg.

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Classification

---

you need classification rather than clustering. what is gene variables' scale. scale /ordinal/ binary ? and i guess target variable is binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the classes yourself, this is *classification*, not clustering.

What you want to do is *supervised feature selection*.

Comment: yes it is binary @whuber

Comment: Exactly ı wanna do supervised feature selection but ı really don't know how ı can do it because ı don't have enough informations neither coding nor classification @Anony-Mousse

Comment: well, i don't use R much, so i can't give you code. But with these terms you can google now easily, I bet tjere are tons of examples for supervised festure selection with R (also look at decision trees etc.)